# Spring Security OncePerRequestFilter not forwarding request to my controller

Tags: spring-security

Spring Security OncePerRequestFilter not forwarding request to my controller.

we have added below mapping in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```